# Partition hard drive to install windows

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-8, partitioning

I need to partition my hard drive to install `Windows`.

My current operating system is `Ubuntu`.

I google'd for `"partition hard disk/drive ubuntu"` - Not much luck. Anything else you suggest me to google? How to partition my hard drive in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Ubuntu help docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Installing_Windows_After_Ubuntu):

```
Installing Windows After Ubuntu
Normally when Windows is installed after Ubuntu the "Master Boot Record", MBR, will be overwritten. You can bootup off a LiveCD and repair the MBR. However, there are 2 different approaches:


Recovering GRUB after reinstalling Windows
Please refer to the Reinstalling GRUB2 guide.

Master Boot Record backup and re-replacement
Back-up the existing MBR, install Windows, replace your backup overwriting the Windows boot code:

Create an NTFS partition for windows (using fdisk, GPartEd or whatever tool you are familiar with)
Backup the MBR e.g. dd if=/dev/sda of=/mbr.bin bs=446 count=1

Install windows
Boot into a LiveCD

Mount your root partition in the LiveCD
Restore the MBR e.g. dd if=/media/sda/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1

Restart and Ubuntu will boot
Setup grub to boot windows
```

Also take a look at the matching [AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/q/129058/116744) and another [AskUbuntu Question](https://askubuntu.com/q/6317/116744) and [this blog article](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2010/05/06/install-windows-after-ubuntu-lucid-lynx/).

Comment: No away around.. without messing the MBR?

Comment: Looks like you will have to do SOMETHING for the bootloader. So I don't think there is another way.

Comment: Actually it looks like you can use a LiveCD and boot-repair as seen in the other linked questions.

Comment: Yeah. that's what the blog says. I need windows for a day, VM is suggested? if yes, Virtual box?

Comment: Well, it depends. VM's have limited preformance compared to a full OS on it's own partition. If you are going to want that preformance and general ease of use you should not use a VM.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to use Windows for one day, as you suggested in your comments, then yes, it's easier to install it on a virtual machine so you don't have MBR issues. You can search for `Virtual Machine` on `Software Center` or google `Virtual Machine Ubuntu` and choose the one you prefer, then follow one of the [many guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+virtual+machine+ubuntu) on how to install Windows on a VM running on Ubuntu. Be aware that, as **CC Inc** mentioned, running Windows on a VM will cause performance loss. Alternatively, to run Windows software on Ubuntu, you can use `Wine` or look for a free alternative.

If you want to dual-boot, you need to resize your Ubuntu partition using GParted Live CD or your Ubuntu Live CD (which contains GParted). Then follow one of the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-7-after-ive-installed-ubuntu) or one of the [many guides](https://www.google.com/search?q=install+windows+after+ubuntu) online to proceed with the installation process.

Resizing / partitioning with GParted is pretty intuitive, and the answers and guides linked above will guide you through the process. If you're still in doubt, [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html) is a very complete guide on how to use GParted.